# Error 406 Not allowed while sending email using php mailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, email

I am facing a problem to send email using php mailer. I follow this article
[Click to see the steps](https://www.formget.com/tracking-email/)

I just download this script and upload on my server (Hostgator). But it is not working..
`It shows 406 not allowed error while sending`

Here is my code in **tracker.php** file

```
    require ('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
    $from = "formget.dev@gmail.com";    //sender's username
    $pwd = "formgetmb";                 //sender's password
//-------------------------------------------------------SEND eMail----------------------------------------------------------------------
if (isset($_POST['mailto'])) {
    try {
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true); //New instance,exceptions enabled with true
        $to = $_POST['mailto'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $id = rand(111, 999);
        $id.=rand(111, 999);
        $body = "This is the fixed message of test email to get notify when it is read.....";
        $body .= "<img border='0' src='http://www.zigsee.com/cvp/Booster/latestemailer/php-track-email/trackonline.php?email=$to&id=$id&subject=$subject' width='1' height='1' alt='image for email' >";
        $mail->IsSMTP();                           // tell the class to use SMTP
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Port = 25;                    // set the SMTP server port
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
        $mail->Username = $from;     // SMTP server username
        $mail->Password = $pwd;            // SMTP server password
        $mail->From = $from;
        $mail->FromName = "TESTUSER";
        $mail->AddAddress($to);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->AltBody = "Please return read receipt to me."; // optional, comment out and test
        $mail->WordWrap = 80; // set word wrap
        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
        $mail->Send();

//return foll
        echo '<input id="id1" name="id" type="hidden" value="' . $id . '">'   
        . '<input id="email1" name="email" type="hidden" value="' . $to . '">'
        . '<label id="label1">Mail sent to <b>' . $to . '<b></label>';
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo $e->errorMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try checking whether mail has been sent or not with if & also shorten the echo just to debugging purpose. Say just mail has been sent or something

Comment: I checked mail not sent..but in article live demo it is working..when i use the whole script on my server..mail not sent by the above code..

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/ try following.

Comment: okay!! i will check with the above code..

Comment: This is in fact a "how to send email with Gmail" kind of question, of which you'll find several dozen dupes. You normally need to enable encryption and take care of two-factor authentication.